# Python type annotation for return values of the same length than *args but different type

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Python supports defining functions that take a variable-length sequence of arguments with `*args`. The type annotation in those cases is expected to describe the type of the individual elements in the sequence. But how can one describe the return type of the function if its length is supposed to depend on the length of `args` and the type of the elements is arbitrary?

Let's consider how we could annotate the output type in the following dubiously useful function:

```py
def add_one_and_to_str(*args):
    return tuple(str(i+1) for i in args)
```

##### Attempt 1: `Sequence`

One option might be to use `Sequence`. For example, one can do

```py
from typing import Sequence

def add_one_and_to_str(*args: int) -> Sequence[str]:
    return tuple(str(i+1) for i in args)
```

This kind of works, but it is loosing information: we know that return type will not be just any sequence of strings but specifically a tuple, and precisely of the same length than the number of arguments provided.

##### Attempt 2: `TypeVarTuple`

As an alternative, Python 3.11 introduces [TypeVarTuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVarTuple), which conceptually, can be thought of as a tuple of type variables (T1, T2, ...).

So you can use it like

```py
from typing import Sequence, TypeVarTuple

Ts = TypeVarTuple('Ts')

def make_tuple(*args: *Ts) -> Tuple[*Ts]:
    return args
```

This correctly propagates the information about the length of the tuple. However, you cannot restrict the input types because [type bounds are still not supported](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#variance-type-constraints-and-type-bounds-not-yet-supported) for `TypeVarTuple` (so you would accept `Any`). But more importantly this seems to be useful in this case only to use the exact same types in the outputs than in the input.

Thus, it doesn't seem to be useful in the case discussed her.

##### Open question

How could the first function be correctly annotated specifying that the output will be a tuple of strings with the same number of elements than integers were provided as function arguments? Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: This is dependent-type territory, which isn't supported at this time. The *length* of a particular value is not part of its type.

Comment: In a type system like that used by Haskell, the length wouldn't really matter. You would simply say that your function has a functor constraint on its argument, which implies that you can only change the *contents* of the container, not the *structure*.

Comment: @chepner Fair enough, but not even the length of tuples?

Comment: Strictly speaking, no.  Each tuple of different length has a *different* type, rather than being instances of a single type indexed by length.

Comment: Making up some syntax, you might imagine a function like `def map(f, xs: list[a][n]) -> list[a][n]: ...`, where the second use of `[]` indicates that the length of both the list argument and the return value have length `n`. Then `def append(xs: list[a][n], x: a) -> list[a][n+1]` would capture the idea that `append` always returns a list that is one longer than the list you started with.

Comment: In the type theory Python is seeking to emulate, a tuple is just a product of types; there is no type like `tuple[int, ...]` that indicates a tuple with one or more `int` values. There are separate types `tuple[int]`, `tuple[int, int]`, `tuple[int, int, int]`, etc. Python is making some compromises between its actual type system and the static type theory it is leveraging to provide type hints.